# Check if string is any combination of multiple word combinations saved in database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I have SQL Server database and application using EF. I want to check a list of word combinations as validation before proceeding with certain functionality.

Table in DB:

| WordCombination |
| --- |
| %lorem%ipsum% |
| ... |

**I have the %lorem%ipsum% in the DB and want to check a string in the .NET application for likeness against it and get boolean result for example "ipsum lorem" should return TRUE**

Currently I have

```
context.Table.Select(row=>row.WordCombination).Any(combination=>EF.Functions.Like(myString,combination))
```

**notice I use the combination from the DB as a pattern**

I try to make the solution as optimal as possible so I don't want to enumerate the table since it may have many rows and I don't want to add any duplicates. Also i try to get only the combination of the two so separating the entry in "lorem" and "ipsum" is not a variant for now.

Is there a way to find both "lorem ipsum","ipsum lorem" and other combinations like "ipsum1234lorem" without adding "ipsum%lorem" entry and without enumerating the table? (with just a query)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's *wrong* with `WHERE YourColumn LIKE '%lorem%ipsum%'`?

Comment: Firstly I want to have only **%lorem%ipsum%** but also catch **ipsum lorem**. Secondly, I don't need a **where** since I don't want to enumerate the query I want only the boolean if such entry exists.

Comment: If you want to check for the existence of *multiple* words, and check they *all* exist, then you need to likely change your design, and instead have one row per word you want to check for. So instead of one row containing `'%lorem%ipsum%'` you should have 2 rows containing `'lorem'` and `'ipsum'`. Then perhaps, you could use a `NOT EXISTS` such as `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable YT WHERE CHARINDEX(OT.Word,YT.YourColumn) = 0);` (Obviously you would also need some method to make the `EXISTS` correlated.)

Comment: The problem is the inputted string (example "ipsum1234lorem") won't be split in any way and it will require some correlation as you say I suppose it can be checked if it's like **ipsum%lorem** , but I ask if there is a way to check it without adding new entries if that is possible. (Also thanks for answering I suspect it may come to adding new entries but also wanted to ask if there is way around it)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the following work?

```
WHERE (YourColumn LIKE '%lorem%' AND YourColumn LIKE '%ipsum%')
OR YourColumn LIKE '%asdf%'
```

Comment: Maybe i haven't asked correctly but the example is the table I currently have of words and word combinations that I want to check against.  When the program receives a new string for example **"ipsum lorem"** I want a query sent to the table in the question and to get whether or not such string was found. As I understood you suggestion suggests I already have the string in the DB and I then check for likeness with specific strings. I want the reversed to have the specific strings in the DB (%lorem%ipsum%) and check the new string without adding to any table. Also it divides the lorem ipsum.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stored procedure like below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE proc_MatchWordCombinations
    @input NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE searchRows CURSOR
    FOR SELECT * FROM WordCombinations;

    DECLARE @searchRow NVARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE @searchParts TABLE(RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), searchPart NVARCHAR(MAX), processed BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)
    DECLARE @searchPart NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @searchPartID INT

    DECLARE @partsToProcess INT
    DECLARE @index INT
    DECLARE @match BIT

    OPEN searchRows
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM searchRows INTO @searchRow

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Search row: ' + @searchRow

        DELETE FROM @searchParts

        INSERT INTO @searchParts (searchPart)
        SELECT value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@searchRow, '%');
        DELETE FROM @searchParts WHERE searchPart = ''

        SELECT @partsToProcess = COUNT(1) FROM @searchParts
        SET @index = 0
        SET @match = 1
        WHILE @index < @partsToProcess
        BEGIN
            SET @index = @index + 1
            PRINT @index
            
            SELECT TOP 1 @searchPart = searchPart, @searchPartID = RowID FROM @searchParts WHERE processed = 0
            UPDATE @searchParts SET processed = 1 WHERE RowID = @searchPartID
            PRINT 'Search part: ' + @searchPart

            IF CHARINDEX(@searchPart, @input) = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @match = 0
                PRINT 'No match: ' + @searchPart
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Match: ' + @searchPart
            END
        END

        IF @match = 1
        BEGIN
            -- The input matches the search row
            PRINT 'Match on: ' + @searchRow
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM searchRows INTO @searchRow
    END

    CLOSE searchRows
    DEALLOCATE searchRows
END
```

And call it like so:

```
EXEC proc_MatchWordCombinations @input = 'ipsum1234lorem'
```